# Change data of arraylist and update data in list using LoaderCallbacks interface

Tags: android

My implementation is like fetch data from web service, add data to arraylist and display it using cuastom adapter. Now here I have used AsyncTaskLoader instead to Asynctask. Till now I am able to display the data from web service. Now I have click listener for each item in my custom adapter. I receive the click for every list item. That I have verified in log. But I want to change the data from the getview method. Like I want to change the background of the row I have clicked and the rest of the row's background remains as it is. But the change is not reflected in the list. Can anybody please tell what am I doing wrong? Or provide some example where the list data is updated from adapter.